# How to force dropdown boostrap buttons in a nav bar to fill the entire container width?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I loaded css and js with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11./jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com
/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In the body of the html I have a container which holds all parts of the page. 
If I use links without a dropdown the buttons auto fill the width of the container.  However, once I switched to drop down buttons, the button widths do not auto size to fill the container.  The code for the navbar is here:

```
 <div class="container">   
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted"></h3>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">


            <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>

                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>              
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  
            </li>
            <li>

            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Home
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  
            </li>





      </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

The container gets closed out later on in the html.  Any help on how to make the button widths autoscale to fill the width of the container would be greatly appreciated.  I can obviously add white space around the button names with &nbsp until the buttons fill the width, but the amount of whitespace required will not be the same for different devices.  I'm thinking a css override will do it, but I have not found one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the display properties of the btn-group and add width to the button.

```
button.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-group {
    display: block;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/shahil/pen/WGbyrK)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it possible by following the steps mentioned below:

1. [Bootstrap's Helper Class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) `center-block` is used to make an element a block element. Use this class with `.btn-group` to make it a block element (Block elements take full browser width by default unless overridden).
2. [Bootstrap's Button Size Class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) `btn-block` can be used to make a button a block button having full available width. You can use this class along with other button classes to have full width buttons.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com
/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">   
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted"></h3>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Home
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```